# ActionScript - Mouse Control Logic Problem

Tags: actionscript-3, logic, mouseevent

i'm attempting to control 2 different shapes (a red rectangle and a blue rectangle) with the same sequence of mouse events (down, move, up), but only one shape at a time must move.

the shapes are locked horizontally along the x-axis.

the red rectangle, which starts out on the left side of the stage, has a right-registration while the the blue rectangle on the right side of the stage has a left-registration.  the rectangle that moves during the MOUSE_MOVE events is the shape that is closest to the *MOUSE_MOVE* event's *stageX* property.

the closest rectangle is determined by averaging the x property of each rectangle (*averageX*)in relation to the MOUSE_MOVE *stageX* property.  therefore, if *stageX* is less than *averageX*, the shape on the left should move.  grater than *averageX*, the shape on the right.

the problem occurs when control changes rectangles during subsequent MOUSE_MOVE events, before MOUSE_UP.  variables that are set during MOUSE_DOWN are appropriate for the rectangle that is moved first, but things become dicey when the other rectangle is to be moved instead.

basically, the rectangle whose *x* property is closest to MOUSE_MOVE event's *stageX* property should move along either left or right with the mouse event, one at a time.

for simplicity with the following code example, a MOUSE_DOWN event could always occur somewhere between the two rectangles.

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//Class
public class RectsTest extends Sprite
    {
    //Variables
    private var redRect:Shape;
    private var blueRect:Shape;

    private var mouseDownOrigin:Number;
    private var redRectOrigin:Number;
    private var blueRectOrigin:Number;
    private var averageX:Number;

    //Constructor
    public function RectsTest()
        {
        init();
        }

    //Initialize 
    private function init():void
        {
        redRect = createRect(0xFF0000, -200, 200, 100);
        redRect.x = 200;
        redRect.y = 200;

        blueRect = createRect(0x0000FF, 0, 200, 100);
        blueRect.x = stage.stageWidth - 200;
        blueRect.y = 300;

        addChild(redRect);
        addChild(blueRect);

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownEventHandler);
        }

    //Create Rect
    private function createRect(color:Number, x:Number, width:Number, height:Number):Shape
        {
        var result:Shape = new Shape();
        result.graphics.beginFill(color);
        result.graphics.drawRect(x, 0, width, height);
        result.graphics.endFill();

        return result;
        }

    //Mouse Down Event Handler
    private function mouseDownEventHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
        mouseDownOrigin = evt.stageX;
        redRectOrigin = redRect.x;
        blueRectOrigin = blueRect.x;

        averageX = (redRect.x + blueRect.x) / 2;

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpEventHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveEventHandler);
        }

    //Mouse Move Event Handler
    private function mouseMoveEventHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
        if  (evt.stageX < averageX)
            redRect.x = redRectOrigin + evt.stageX - mouseDownOrigin;

        if  (evt.stageX > averageX)
            blueRect.x = blueRectOrigin + evt.stageX - mouseDownOrigin;

        averageX = (redRect.x + blueRect.x) / 2;
        }

    //Mouse Up Event Handler
    private function mouseUpEventHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpEventHandler);
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveEventHandler);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check, which Rect will be moved before registering mouseMoveHandler. And then change the position of necessary rectangle. I used currentRect variable to represent movable rect:

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//Class
public class RectsTest extends Sprite
    {
    //Variables
    private var redRect:Shape;
    private var blueRect:Shape;

    private var mouseDownOrigin:Number;
    private var redRectOrigin:Number;
    private var blueRectOrigin:Number;
    private var averageX:Number;

    //Constructor
    public function RectsTest()
        {
        init();
        }

    //Initialize 
    private function init():void
        {
        redRect = createRect(0xFF0000, -200, 200, 100);
        redRect.x = 200;
        redRect.y = 200;

        blueRect = createRect(0x0000FF, 0, 200, 100);
        blueRect.x = stage.stageWidth - 200;
        blueRect.y = 300;

        addChild(redRect);
        addChild(blueRect);

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownEventHandler);
        }

    //Create Rect
    private function createRect(color:Number, x:Number, width:Number, height:Number):Shape
        {
        var result:Shape = new Shape();
        result.graphics.beginFill(color);
        result.graphics.drawRect(x, 0, width, height);
        result.graphics.endFill();

        return result;
        }

    //Mouse Down Event Handler
    private function mouseDownEventHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
        mouseDownOrigin = evt.stageX;
        redRectOrigin = redRect.x;
        blueRectOrigin = blueRect.x;

        averageX = (redRect.x + blueRect.x) / 2;

        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpEventHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveEventHandler);
        }

    //Mouse Move Event Handler
    private function mouseMoveEventHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
        if  (evt.stageX < averageX) {
            redRect.x = redRectOrigin + evt.stageX - mouseDownOrigin;
            redRectOrigin = redRect.x;
        }


        if  (evt.stageX > averageX) {
            blueRect.x = blueRectOrigin + evt.stageX - mouseDownOrigin;
            blueRectOrigin = blueRect.x;
        }

        mouseDownOrigin = evt.stageX;
        averageX = (redRect.x + blueRect.x) / 2;
        }

    //Mouse Up Event Handler
    private function mouseUpEventHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpEventHandler);
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveEventHandler);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you misunderstood since you code doesn't work.  the shape that moves should be able to change during dragging.  so if i'm dragging the red rectangle to the right of the screen, as soon as the stageX is closer to the blue rectangle then the red rectangle will stop moving while the blue rectangle begines to move - all before mouse up.

Comment: ok, i realized, that my code was wrong. i'm tried to reset values of redRectOrigin (blueRectOrigin) and mouseDownOrigin in your code, and it's work, but has some bugs (when i move cursor to left and right quickly near the middle rectangles are moving apart from each other). See the code above

Comment: ah, i see how you corrected my mistake.  forgot to account for the new rectangle origins during move.  the bug is a bit surprising, and the overall performance seems very bad - it's laggy even in the stand alone debugger, or maybe it's just appearing like that because of the bug.